# Can I write a function in Blazor that dynamically renders elements in a View?

Tags: razor, mvvm, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have an object called BusinessUnit which contains a list of child business units and I need a function that renders < li> elements for every child under its parent. The code I have so far is below:

```
<ul id="Level0">
    @foreach (var bizUnit in businessUnitViewModel.BusinessUnitInfos)
    {
        <li>
            <span>@bizUnit.BusinessUnitName</span>
                <ul class="nested">
                    @foreach (var childOfbizUnit in bizUnit.Children)
                    {
                        <li>@childOfbizUnit.BusinessUnitName</li>
                    }
                </ul>
        </li>
    }
</ul>
```

The nested foreach is basically the same as the first one, but hardcoding them limits how many hierarchical levels I can have. I need a function like this:

```
 public void HasKids(BusinessUnitInfo bizUnit)
    {
        foreach (var bizUnitChild in bizUnit.Children)
        {
            //Render an <li> tag element with bizUnitChild's 
            name<li>bizUnitChild.Name</li>

            HasKids(bizUnitChild);
        }
    }
```

Does anyone know what I can do for the comment in the last code block; can I use C# code to dynamically render a list tag? Thans :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If the structure is a tree then you effectively need a recursive component.

**Note**: For performance reasons you should always use the `@key` directive when generating UI markup from a loop. You can read more at [Blazor University](https://blazor-university.com/components/render-trees/optimising-using-key/).

```
<li>
  @Item.Name
  if (@Item.Children.Any())
  {
    <ul id="@level">
      @foreach(var child in Item.Children)
      {
        <ShowItem Item=@child Level="@(Level + 1)" @key=child/>
      }
    </ul>
  }
</li>

@code {
  [Parameter] MyElementClass Item { get; set; }
  [Parameter] int Level { get; set; }
}
```

In your main page, you just do this

```
<ul level="0">
  @foreach(var item in TopLevelItems)
  {
    <ShowItem Item=@item Level=1 @key=item/>
  }
</ul>
```

Comment: This is correct, but it should be noted that this will potentially result in multiple `<ul>` elements with the same `id` (which is invalid) since more than one sublist might have the same level.  Probably should use some form of `class` instead.

Comment: @KirkWoll Nope, the embedded components pass (@Level + 1) when recursing

Comment: You can still have siblings that will have the same level.  If `Item.Children` contains more than one item, naturally you will have two instances of `ShowItem` with the same `Level + 1` value, and thus multiple `<ul>` elements with the same id.

Comment: Ah yes, you are right. Would have to pass a path instead.

Answer (score 2):

I made some improvements for Peter Morris's code:

```
<li>
  @Item.Name
  @if (Item.Children != null && Item.Children.Any())
  {
    <ul class="@Level">
      @foreach(var child in Item.Children)
      {
        <ShowItem Item=@child Level="@(Level + 1)" @key=child/>
      }
    </ul>
  }
</li>

@code {
  [Parameter] public MyElementClass Item { get; set; }
  [Parameter] public int Level { get; set; }
}
```

I added null check, because I had problems when the property was null, fixed a typo in the Id of the ul and changed the id to class.